# How to get the result of the substraction of 2 attributes

Tags: xml, xpath

Consider this simple xml

```
<books>
  <book>
    <price ht="100" ttc="120"/>
  </book>
  <book>
    <price ht="150" ttc="180"/>
  </book>
</books>
```

I want to list the substraction of `ttc` and `ht` for all `book/price` node (ttc - ht)

I know how to obtain the ttc: `//book[price]/price/@ttc` and the ht same way.

How to obtain the result of ttc - ht ?

Comment: I don't think you can do that with straight xpath.  Can you use xquery?

Comment: Thanks. My question was merely theoretical because I learn xpath. I've readen that minus operator exists but have found no example of this (ex here : https://www.educba.com/xpath-operators/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
//book/price/(./@ttc - ./@ht)
```

Given your sample xml, output is:

```
20
30
```

Answer (score 1):

To retrieve the difference per `book` element, you can use this XSL code in combination with the *Identity template*:

```
<xsl:template match="book">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:value-of select="price/@ttc - price/@ht" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

It emits the difference for each `<book>` element.

---

To get the total difference of all `<book>` element's attributes, you can use the following XPath-1.0 expression:

```
<xsl:template match="books">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:value-of select="sum(.//book/price/@ttc) - sum(.//book/price/@ht)" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

The core XPath-1.0 expression is, starting from the level of `<books>`, this one:

```
sum(.//book/price/@ttc) - sum(.//book/price/@ht)
```

This expression subtracts all `@ht` attributes from all `@ttc` attributes. The `.//` operator means, that all descendant elements starting from the current axis are selected. In the above XSLT code, the *current axis* is `<books>`.

So in the above example case, the result is `50`.